# Is there a way to change method parameter list intellij?

Tags: java, methods, intellij-idea, parameters

To be generalized, Let's take an example like this.

I have a method something like this.

```
public void mymethod(int param1, String param2){
    //do something
}
```

And I want to change it into something like this.

```
public void mymethod(int param1, String param2, String param3){
    //do something
}
```

Is there a preferred way to do that with intellij without breaking usages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the followings with intellij.

With `Refactor` -> `Change Signature` menu, you can:

- Change the method name, return type and visibility scope.
- Add new parameters and remove the existing ones. Note that you can also add a parameter using a dedicated Extract Parameter refactoring.
- Reorder parameters.
- Change parameter names and types.
- Add and remove exceptions.
- Propagate new parameters and exceptions through the method call hierarchy.

To go to `Refactor` -> `Change Signature` menu

In the editor, place the cursor within the name of the method whose signature you want to change.
Do one of the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.
- Choose Refactor | Change Signature in the main menu.
- Select Refactor | Change Signature from the context menu (right-click).

For more, please have a look at [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/change-method-signature-in-java.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on method name, then `refactor` -> `change signature` (or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> if you are on a mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> in Windows, Linux).

A new window should open where you can add and remove new parameters, as well as change the visibility of your method.

Answer (score 2):

From a clean code perspective, the answer is simple: don't do that - the less arguments your methods have, the better!

**Adding** a third parameter looks like taking a really wrong route to me.

Probably your favorite idea can change all your client code to use null or some empty string for the new argument ... but again: that "smells" bad too me.

You see: your code should be verbose on the one hand, but as "concise" as possible. Meaning: each and any argument on your methods do exist because your code needs them. So, if you are about to add a third argument, that maybe most of the time is null; and only in those places where you want it to "mean" something it is non-null, well, my two cent: don't do that: as obviously, the two-arg+null method will be doing something else than the three-arg method. If so - keep two separate methods.

Keep in mind: each argument that you add to your method adds more variety to your testing scope. You really don't want that. Your methods should be as simple as possible, so they can be tested as easily as possible.

Comment: I am asking this question just to know whether there's any IDE shortcut. not in oop perspective. You can see that I have taken a dummy example. :)

Comment: @AdInfinitum no problem of that :), there are things to be taken from his answer. And I didn't down vote it either.

Comment: @Jagermeister at the same time if you are using modern DI framework like Guice, you may have noticed that those kind of situations can happen. And agree with you that it is kinda bad idea in oop perspective.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne You are welcome; and I am glad that you got the concrete answers you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the some missing points here.

- Adding a parameter, changing a parameter type, changing return type of the method will not be much automated with an IDE.

Reason is that IDE cannot guess and create or replace the assignments for the changed parameter or method usage.

- Adding/changing an exception will also be pretty much semi-automated, because IDE doesn't know whether try/catch or passing exception with the method usages. You have to manually go through each and do what you want at each place.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the method name, then refactor -> change signature (Ctrl + F6 in Windows).